# Mongoose not adding to an array of objects

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I'm using Mongoose to insert an item into this property of the schema:

```
reactedBy: [
        {
        userId: {
            type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User",
            required: true
        },
        isLike: {
            type: Boolean,
            required: true
        }
    }
]
```

It should accept the following data structure an array of objects:

```
[
  {userId: ObjectId(some id), isLike: {true or false}}
]
```

Here's the code I'm using:

```
await Review.updateOne(
        { _id: parsedRequest.id },
        { $push: { reactedBy: {userId: user._id, isLike: parsedRequest.like} } }
    );
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
 ⨯ CastError: Cast to [ObjectId] failed for value  {
  stringValue: '"[ { userId: new ObjectId("64e15e9d29617fb0163de01b"), isLike: true } ]"',
  messageFormat: undefined,
  kind: '[ObjectId]',
  value: '[ { userId: new ObjectId("64e15e9d29617fb0163de01b"), isLike: true } ]',
  path: 'reactedBy.0',
  reason: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ userId: new ObjectId("64e15e9d29617fb0163de01b"), isLike: true }" (type Object) at path "reactedBy" because of "BSONError"
      at  {
    stringValue: '"{ userId: new ObjectId("64e15e9d29617fb0163de01b"), isLike: true }"',
    messageFormat: undefined,
    kind: 'ObjectId',
    value: { userId: new ObjectId("64e15e9d29617fb0163de01b"), isLike: true },
    path: 'reactedBy',
    reason: BSONError: Argument passed in must be a string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters or an integer
       
    valueType: 'Object'
  },
  valueType: 'string'
}
```

Here's the full Schema file `review.ts`:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const ReviewSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    text: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    stars: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    },
    isReviewOnCustomer: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: true,
    },
    author: {
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: "User",
    },
    recipient: {
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: "User",
    },
    comments: [
        {
            type: {
                text: {
                    type: String,
                },
                author: {
                    type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
                    ref: "User",
                },
            },
            required: false,
        },
    ],
    likes: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        default: 0,
    },
    reactedBy: [
        {
        userId: {
            type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User",
            required: true
        },
        isLike: {
            type: Boolean,
            required: true
        }
    }
    ],
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        required: true,
        default: () => Date.now(),
    },
    updatedAt: Date,
});

export default mongoose.models.Review || mongoose.model("Review", ReviewSchema);
```

What's wrong with the mongoose code? Is the schema or the update function the problem?

Comment: Could you try to create model first and then push it. Create a variable model that includes the userId and other fields. Then, set it as normal; {$push: { reactedBy: model }}. Also, you might use findByIdAndUpdate here since need to find the field first and then update

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. Can you please show some more code.

Comment: Can you share more of your schema becuase `reason: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ userId: new ObjectId("64e15e9d29617fb0163de01b"), isLike: true }" (type Object) at path "reactedBy" because of "BSONError"` suggests that mongoose thinks `reactedBy` should be an `ObjectId` and not an object like your post indicates. If you query your documents using mongosh or Compass, what are the data types of elements in `reactedBy` array of each document?

Comment: @JQeeny Updated my question.

Comment: Your `Review.updateOne()` works perfectly on my local machine. What is the value of  `parsedRequest.id` in the `updateOne`? Can you `console.log(parsedRequest.id)` just before you run the update.

Comment: It outputs `650652bc7789bd923e11e7ce`

Comment: Please post the part of your code that calls `await Review.updateOne`, is it in a route? I need to see where `parsedRequest` is coming from. Can also `console.log(user._id)` before you run the update because it looks like you are passing an object instead of id? Please post an image of the document from compass that you are trying to update. Is it possible you already created the document with a different datatype for `reactedBy` previously and *then* updated your schema at a later date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are using a user object id instead of search review object id.

Answer (score 0):

Try to manually cast the userId to an ObjectId using mongoose.Types.ObjectId like this:

```
await Review.updateOne(
    { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(parsedRequest.id) },
    { $push: { reactedBy: { userId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(user._id), isLike: parsedRequest.like } } }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your code is related to the data structure you’re trying to push into the reactedBy array in your Mongoose schema. The reactedBy array expects an array of objects, where each object contains userId as a mongoose.Types.ObjectId and isLike as a Boolean. However, in your update operation, it seems that you’re pushing an object containing a mix of actual values and placeholders. This is causing a CastError.

To resolve this, you should ensure that the object you’re pushing into the reactedBy array follows the schema structure. Here’s how you can update your code:

```html
await Review.updateOne(
    { _id: parsedRequest.id },
    {
        $push: {
            reactedBy: {
                userId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(user._id), // Convert to ObjectId
                isLike: parsedRequest.like
            }
        }
    }
);
```

In this code, I’ve made sure that userId is properly converted to a mongoose.Types.ObjectId, and isLike is assigned from parsedRequest.like. This should match the schema structure and resolve the CastError issue.